# Python TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable when sorting dictionary

Tags: python, pytorch

Here is my code. The packages imported are not shown. I am trying to feed the CIFAR-10 test data into alexnet. The dictionary at the end needs to be sorted so I can find the most common classification. Please help, I have tried everything!

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
alexnet = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)

transform = transforms.Compose([            #[1]
 transforms.Resize(256),                    #[2]
 transforms.CenterCrop(224),                #[3]
 transforms.ToTensor(),                     #[4]
 transforms.Normalize(                      #[5]
 mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],                #[6]
 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]                  #[7]
 )])

# Getting the CIFAR-10 dataset
dataset = CIFAR10(root='data/', download=True, transform=transform)
test_dataset = CIFAR10(root='data/', train=False, transform=transform)

classes = dataset.classes
#print(classes)

torch.manual_seed(43)
val_size = 10000
train_size = len(dataset) - val_size

train_ds, val_ds = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])

#print(len(train_ds), len(val_ds))

batch_size=100

train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True)

with open("/home/shaan/Computer Science/CS4442/Ass4/imagenet_classes.txt") as f:
    classes = eval(f.read())

holder = []
dic = {}

current = ''
#data_iter = iter(test_loader)
#images,labels = data_iter.next()
    
#alexnet.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in test_loader:
        images, labels = data
        out = alexnet(images)
        #print(out.shape)    


        for j in range(0,batch_size):
            sorted, indices = torch.sort(out,descending=True)
            percentage = F.softmax(out,dim=1)[j]*100
            results = [(classes[i.item()],percentage[i].item()) for i in indices[j][:5]]
            holder.append(results[0][0])


holder.sort()
for z in holder:
    if current != z:
        count = 1
        dic[z] = count
        current = z
        
    else:
        count = count + 1
        dic[z] = count 
        current = z
```

This is where im getting the error:

```
for w in sorted(dic, key=dic.get, reverse=True):
    print(w, dic[w])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
sorted, indices = torch.sort(out,descending=True)
```

You created a variable named `sorted`, which is exactly the same name as `sorted` function you call when it error.

Just change this to something else like

```
sorted_out, indices = torch.sort(out,descending=True)
```